# Web API end point not working from postman but from swagger

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I am working on WebAPI .Net Core 2.2, I have successfully added swagger and from swagger UI I am able to create POST or GET request. But when I execute endpoint from Postman nothing happened. Even break point hit on endpoint but proper result is not shown on postman UI

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("Details/{year:int}/Directors")]
public ActionResult DirectoryMoviesByYear(int year) 
{
     //sample code 
     return Ok(new Director { Id=1, Name="Peter Jackson" });

}
```

end point used in Postman
https://localhost:44386/api/Movie/Details/1980/Directors

here is swagger screen shot
[result from swagger](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rs7Z8.png)
here is postman screen shot
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sDPkk.png)

Comment: What does `proper result is not shown on postman UI,` mean? What *do* you get back in Postman? What status code, response body?

Comment: @zeeshan can you post a screenshot of your postman?

Comment: screen shot from swagger and postman added. hope you guys understand the issue

Answer (score 23):

Looks like you are using self-signed certificate for https and `Postman` just blocks request because of it. Configure `Postman` to not verify *SSL* cetrificates in *File -> Settings*

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Make Sure You OFF SSL certificate validation From Postman -> Preferences -> General -> SSL certificate validation -> OFF

and it's Working for me

Answer (score 0):

In case someone stumbles upon this in the future, make sure that if you have an `[Authorize]` tag in your method, you call your login endpoint first. Apparently there is no need to do this in Swagger but you need to do it in Postman.